# Code pushed to Azure App Service using FTP not reflecting in application

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I have pushed the changes in my code using FTP to Azure App Service. I can see these changes in the App Editor (Preview) Section, as well as in Kudu. This code is integrated with Azure Bot and uses Microsoft Teams as a channel, to create a Teams Chat Bot.

The issue- even though I can see the changes in code (App Service Editor and Kudu), the application/bot is not showing the updated results. It is still rendering the old results even though that part of the code is removed. What am I missing out here?

P.S. I'm using Node.js if this is relevant.

Edit- I am only pushing the files through FTP that I have edited/changed, the files that are unchanged are not pushed again.

Answer (score 0):

- I have created 2 NodeJS Web Apps one with Windows and other Linux App service.
- When I try to upload files from FTP with some changes to Windows App service, I can see the changes reflecting immediately.
- Whereas for Linux App service plan, Iam unable to see the new changes uploaded by FTP.
- Try to restart the App in Azure Portal and check once.
- As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#i-m-using-my-own-custom-container--i-want-the-platform-to-mount-an-smb-share-to-the---home---directory-),

> Check whether `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` value in Configuration => Appsettings section is set to true or not. It has to be set to true.

- As per @[cephalin](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32572#issuecomment-551053105) comment,

> If your Web App is deployed to Linux App service, then we have to specify the runtime

- Make sure you are using the latest version of [HTTP](https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/bc_azr_networking_8), as highlighted in the below screenshot.

[image]